# Couldn't find Post without an ID even though request parameters says I do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

To me this is a strange one.

I have 2 models (with User), I have post and I have comment.
What I am trying to do is to have the form_for comments in the post#show view.

However for some reason when I try to create a comment I get Couldn't find Post without an ID. 
When I look at the request parameters though I see:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7bAXF66sghTKAF7b61gu08hElC+O1nR6RoT92tqQGOI=",     "comment"=>{"content"=>"ok"}, "commit"=>"Add comment", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"comments", "post_id"=>"23"}
```

which clearly shows that it does in-fact get the post_id and that it is in this case the id of 23.

After countless hours I thought that I'd see if you guys have a solution.

My **comments_controller.rb**:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :load_post

 def create
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:content])
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
   @comment.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
   redirect_to root_url, notice: "Comment was created."
  else
   render :new
 end

 def load_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

My **posts_controller.rb**

```
  def show
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

the partial for the forms **comments/_form.rb**

```
<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :content %>
 <%= f.submit "Add comment" %>
<% end %>
```

My **routes.rb**

```
  resources :posts do 
   resources :comments 
  end
```

my **posts/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render @post %>

 <h3>New comment</h3>

 <%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

my **posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<h2><%= @post.title %></h2>
<p><%= @post.content %></p>
<em>written by <%= @post.user.fullname %></em>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving `"post_id"` not as `"id"`

You can make `load_post` action as private for security concerns

```
private

 def load_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 end
```

Access the `content` like

```
def create
 @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment][:content]) 
....
```

Comment: Great, that seemed to work but caused another error, it doesn't seem to save the :content. It does however save the id, user_id and post_id. Any thoughts?

Comment: you can tick the answer if this has helped, for you question, check A I have updated.